# Some html items shift down after adding Bootstrap CDN

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

After I add Bootstrap CDN all some of my html elements shift down. Such as nav bar, p's in footer. This happens exactly after adding a link to the header. If I comment it out the problem disappears.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-width: 800px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}

.base {
  background: #333333;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.logo:hover {
  background: #404040;
}

#logo_img {
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "Calibri";
  font-size: 20px;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: #404040;
}

#social {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 7px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

#social li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

#social li:hover {
  background: #404040;
}

#social img {
  height: 35px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: default;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}

footer a {
  color: #007acc;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #007acc;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer p {
  color: #e6e6e6;
  margin: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode";
}

#info {
  float: left;
}

#footer_name {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>

    <link type="text/css" href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">

    <!--Bootstrap links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="base">

      <div class="logo">
        <a href="#"><img id="logo_img" src="img/logo.png"></a>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <ul>
          <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">Home</span></li></a>
          <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">Diary</span></li></a>
          <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">Foods</span></li></a>
          <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">Settings</span></li></a>
          <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">About</span></li></a>
        </ul>
      </nav>

      <div id="social">
        <ul>
          <a href="#"><li><img class="social_icons" src="img/facebookc.png"></li></a>
          <a href="#"><li><img class="social_icons" src="img/twitterc.png"></li></a>
          <a href="#"><li><img class="social_icons" src="img/instagramc.png"></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>

    <footer class="base">
      <p id="info">This website was created by a student of Wroclaw University of Technology.&emsp;<a href="#">Contacts</a></p>
      <p id="footer_name">Copyright &copy; 2016 FitIt, Inc.</p>
    </footer>


    <!--Scripts-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

[Bottom pic navbar and social icons and text in footer are shifted...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dux7d.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened is you added some new styles via Bootstrap, which conflict with your existing CSS properties.

For the navbar links, the problem is here:

bootstrap.min.css:5 (line 5)

```
ol, ul {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
```

Add a property to your navbar ul like this:

```
<ul style="margin-bottom:0px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is always a problem when using common tags like `<nav>`,`<header>`,`<footer>` and etc.. because those elements are styled using Bootstrap, and makes conflict with existing styles.

you have several ways:

1) to make the current/existing style declarations more strict, i.e.

```
nav ul li { property:value!important;}
```

2) change the tagnames like this:

and then

```
nav.mynav ul li {property:value;}
```

3) change `nav` and etc tags with classified `div`, so you will have i.e.:

```
 <div class="my_navig">
    <ul>
      <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">Home</span></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">Diary</span></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">Foods</span></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">Settings</span></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li><span class="menu_item">About</span></li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put the `p` tags inside a container like so:

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Bootstrap needs a proper block container inside that footer block, just like you have in your header block for the `a`.